# Unable to push to newly created Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my local git repository to my newly created 
Bitbucket repository.

What I did:

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPONAME.git`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m 'Initial commit'`
5. `git push -u origin master`

Instead of pushing, I receive:

```
repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I `cat .git/config`, I can see the correct URL which should be used:

`url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPONAME.git`

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working. I've set up a repository in the same way yesterday and all went fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you successfully set up your SSH key? Did you get the remote URL by copying from Bitbucket to ensure there aren't any typos?

Comment: @Chris, I do. I've always been using SSH. And yes, I always copy the URL to avoid typos.

Comment: What does `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently changed my Bitbucket username and when I ran `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` in console, it printed my new username. Whenever I changed it back to my previous username, it all worked.